# mysql fulltext index search in boolean mode union with a like based search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

While searching through my database, I want the really relevant results (the one's returned by my boolean search) ranked up, but at the same time I do not want the somewhat less relevant (like) results completely omitted.

Currently my query looks like this.

```
(SELECT *, MATCH (col1,col2,col3,col4) AGAINST (query* in boolean mode) AS score
FROM table where match(col1,col2,col3,col4) against (query* in boolean mode)
order by score DESC) 
   UNION (SELECT * from table where col1 like query 
          or col2 like query or col2 like query or col4 like query)
```

This returns an error which states that the given two select clauses have a different number of columns. I understand this is because 'score' is being added as a column in the first part of the query.
Is there a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a fake column score to the second query as well using column alias. You don't need to use that value but will make the union work.
e.g.:

```
(SELECT *, MATCH (col1,col2,col3,col4) AGAINST (query* in boolean mode) AS score
FROM table where match(col1,col2,col3,col4) against (query* in boolean mode)
order by score DESC) 
UNION (SELECT *, 50 as score from table where col1 like query 
or col2 like query or col2 like query or col4 like query)
```

You can replace 50 by any default score you wish to assign.